# libc++ std::istringstream doesn't thrown exceptions. Bug?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, libc++

After configuring a `std::istringstream` to throw exceptions when `failbit` is set I get no exceptions happening with libc++ (this is under linux with libc++ compiled with support from libcxxrt). I suppose this is a bug in libc++ or libcxxrt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T> std::istream &getvalue(std::istream &is, T &value, const T &default_value = T())
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s;
    std::getline(is, s, ',');
    ss << s;
    if((ss >> value).fail())
        value = default_value;
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "123,456,789";
    std::istringstream is(s);
    unsigned n;

    try
    {
        is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::eofbit);

        getvalue(is, n);
        std::cout << n << std::endl;

        getvalue(is, n);
        std::cout << n << std::endl;

        // Disable EOF exception on last bit
        is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);

        getvalue(is, n);
        std::cout << n << std::endl;

        // Force Fail reading after EOF
        getvalue(is, n);
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::ios::failure &fail)
    {
        std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output for libstdc++:

```
123
456
789
Fail
```

libc++/libcxxrt output:

```
123
456
789
0
```

#### EDIT

Also tested on OS X.

Bug submitted: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15949

Comment: Is it possible that `_LIBCPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is set in your compilation options?

Comment: @ecatmur, no, I don't set it.

Answer (score 4):

libc++ is responding to 27.7.2.1 [istream]/p4 which describes the `basic_istream` parse `operator>>` for `unsigned`:

> If one of these called functions throws an exception, then unless
>   explicitly noted otherwise, the input function sets badbit in error
>   state. If badbit is on in exceptions(), the input function rethrows
>   the exception without completing its actions, otherwise it does not
>   throw anything and proceeds as if the called function had returned a
>   failure indication.

If:

```
is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
```

then the desired behavior is obtained.

```
123
456
789
Fail
```

**Update**

chico rightly pointed out in the comments below that he expected `getline(is, s, ',')` to throw, not the `unsigned` extractor.

Looking at 21.4.8.9 [string.io]/p7 which describes this `getline`:

> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (27.7.2.3), except
>   that it does not affect the value returned by subsequent calls to
>   basic_istream<>::gcount(). After constructing a sentry object, if the
>   sentry converts to true, calls str.erase() and then extracts
>   characters from is and appends them to str as if by calling
>   str.append(1, c) until any of the following occurs:  ...

So the question becomes:

> How does an unformatted input function behave?

27.7.2.3 [istream.unformatted]/p1 says:

> Each unformatted input function begins execution by constructing an
>   object of class sentry with the default argument noskipws (second)
>   argument true. If the sentry object returns true, when converted to a
>   value of type bool, the function endeavors to obtain the requested
>   input. Otherwise, if the sentry constructor exits by throwing an
>   exception or if the sentry object returns false, when converted to a
>   value of type bool, the function returns without attempting to obtain
>   any input. In either case the number of extracted characters is set to
>   0; unformatted input functions taking a character array of non-zero
>   size as an argument shall also store a null character (using charT())
>   in the first location of the array. **If an exception is thrown during
>   input then ios::badbit is turned on<sup>315</sup> in *this’s error state.
>   (Exceptions thrown from basic_ios<>::clear() are not caught or
>   rethrown.) If (exceptions()&badbit) != 0 then the exception is
>   rethrown.** It also counts the number of characters extracted. If no
>   exception has been thrown it ends by storing the count in a member
>   object and returning the value specified. In any event the sentry
>   object is destroyed before leaving the unformatted input function.
>
> 315) This is done without causing an ios::failure to be thrown.

(emphasis added by me for readability purposes)

So this again appears to indicate that if an exception is desired from this parse operation, `badbit` has to be set in `exceptions`.

Comment: Does "`unsigned`" matter? `std::getline(is, s, ',');` is the line that should throw, it doesn't involve reading into `unsigned`.

Comment: In the end I got the impression, "Why can't it be just that simple? If I wan't to set exceptions for some given flags, just set it for such. But no, I must insert `badbit` out of nowhere..."

Comment: [This libc++ bug was closed as invalid](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15949), but I don't believe it is. The reasons that `failbit` is set: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_failbit differ from the reasons that `badbit` is set: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_badbit It's completely realistic that I may want to *only* throw if a `failbit` was set and *not* if a `badbit` was set. Because of this but libc++ now requires a painstaking workaround, particularly for compound extraction operators: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35020134/2642059

Comment: I have linked a question on [LWG2349](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2349) in this question's duplicate and I believe it is relevant here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088800/what-effect-would-lwg2349-have

Comment: @HowardHinnant: What does the creation of the `basic_istream::sentry` object supposed to do? I don't have a copy of the Standard, but [from](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedInputFunction) [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sentry) it appears as if the sentry-creation of the fourth `std::getline()` call should have detected that `eofbit` is already set in `is` and therefore should have set `failbit` (and thrown an exception in doing so).

Comment: @Tanz87:  Here's a link to the latest working draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf  It says that for unformatted functions a sentry should not skip white space, and if the sentry returns false it should set `badbit`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks. Note that you said "if the sentry **returns** false ...". If the sentry threw an exception **during its construction** we won't even get to that. In §27.7.2.1.3 paragraph 1 (`sentry` constructor): "_Effects:_ If `is.good()` is `false`, calls `is.setstate(failbit)`." -- which, from §27.5.5.4 paragraph 6 (`basic_ios::setstate` method): "_Effects:_ Calls `clear(rdstate() | state)` (which may throw `basic_ios::failure` (27.5.3.1.1))."

Comment: Another thing: §27.7.2.3 paragraph 1 (unformatted input functions) says: "If the `sentry` object returns `true`, when converted to a value of type `bool`, the function endeavors to obtain the requested input. Otherwise, if the `sentry` constructor exits by throwing an exception or if the `sentry` object returns `false`, when converted to a value of type `bool`, the function returns without attempting to obtain any input." From this it would seem that `getline` shouldn't throw on `sentry`-construction failure by exception (effectively going against my previous comment) ... **<<continued>>**

Comment: However, in §21.3.2.9 (`getline` for `basic_string`) paragraph 9: "If the function extracts no characters, it calls `is.setstate(ios_base::failbit)` which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4)." -- This bit seems to be an additional requirement on `getline` for `basic_string` (regardless of `sentry`-construction failure or failure in extracting input), beyond what is commonly required for unformatted input functions.

Comment: @Tanz87:  I recommend filing a bug report here if you believe libc++ is in error:  https://llvm.org/bugs/  I am no longer a maintainer of libc++.