# Exception is not handled on fstream open

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, system-error

## Context

I have this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <system_error>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::ifstream file;
  file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);

  try {
    file.open("a_file_does_not_exist.txt", std::ios::in);
    file.close();
  } catch(const std::ios_base::failure& err) {
    std::cerr << err.code() << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Just to complete, this is compile command:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -g //  ...
```

The version of compiler is *g++ (GCC) 6.1.1*.

Platform: *arch-linux 4.7.2-1*.

---

## The problem

As you can imagine, the file does not exists so the method `file.open(...)` will throw an exception. The problem is when I run the code *an exception is not handled*, and `std::terminate` is called.

The strange thing is the output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear
Annullato (core dump creato)
```

As you can read, the throwing class is a `std::ios_base::failure`, but my catch is right that class.

My question is: what am I missing?

Comment: [Confirmed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a72462c322e96f)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088800/what-effect-would-lwg2349-have/35089910#35089910

Comment: Works as expected with g++ 5.4.0

Comment: Hmm, even the program given in the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) doesn't catch the exception and does the same thing. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdc297ab38aae8ec)

Comment: Failing [on Clang 3.8.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/554953555f976112). Definitely a bug.

Comment: Catching the exception as an `exception`, type id reports the mangled type name `NSt8ios_base7failureE`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf but if you throw one manually, it's [`NSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/224da5107c3d0ed0). Maybe there's two definitions in the codebase, one for C++03 and one for C++11, and 03 hides 11 in `open`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, actually, ... I was trying to understand something there...

Comment: @jaggedSpire: Yeah, two definitions sounds reasonable. A single definition should produce the same mangled name.

Comment: Yep, `ios_base::failure` underwent an ABI change in C++11. libstdc++ messed up a bit here trying to manage the transition. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145

Comment: This is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40246459/981959 (I initially marked it as a dup of another one, and now can't re-close it again as the right dup).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `file.good()` and `file.fail()` for exception handling. It would work perfectly for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it's not an answer to the question.