# Exception not caught opening a non-existing file using C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I was running a MWE from here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/
On my machine it does not catch the exception.  Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
    try
    {
        file.open("IDoNotExist.txt");
    }
    catch(const std::ifstream::failure& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Bad luck!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Using `gcc 6.2.1` on Arch-Linux I get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
>
> what(): basic_ios::clear

However, on the link posted above it is mentioned that the code should also catch the exception related to opening the file.  What went wrong?

Comment: That looks like a bad example.  For one thing the exception should be captured by const reference like you do but they do not.

Comment: With g++ 6.2.0 on (a different distribution of) Linux, this program prints "Bad luck!".  I also know that this program _should_ catch the `failure` exception and print "Bad luck!" (assuming `IDoNotExist.txt` genuinely does not exist).  Therefore, your C++ compiler and/or runtime are malfunctioning.  The most probable reason for this is that they are mis-installed.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling every package with `g++` or `c++` in its name.

Comment: While cplusplus.com have its positive sides, it also have its negative sides (there are divided oppinions about the site, search for it if you want to know more). I tend to prefer [this reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) instead, and it seems to be more up to date and accurate. For example it's example on [I/O stream exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) uses the correct class to catch.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That example code also fails.  It also does not capture by const reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's true, but at least it catches by reference.

Comment: @zwol I reinstalled all base and base developer packages on Arch but the behaviour does not change.

Comment: @MrZ It's probably g++ 6.2.0 bug or something: I'm also on Arch with gcc, and I get the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a [known bug in libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145).

The problem is that with the change to the C++11 ABI, many classes were duplicated in `libstdc++6.so`, one version with the old ABI, other with the new one.

Exception classes were not duplicated so this problem didn't exist at the time. But then, in some newer revision of the language, it was decided that `std::ios_base::failure` should derive from `std::system_error` instead of `std::exception`... but `system_error` is a C++11 only class so it must use the new ABI flag or it will complain. Now you have two different `std::ios_base::failure` classes and a mess in your hands!

The easy solution is to compile your program with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and resign to the old ABI until the bug is solved. Or alternatively, write `catch (std::exception &e)`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To be completely accurate, the problem is not that `system_error` is C++11-only (that could be solved) but that `std::system_error` has a different size and layout to `std::exception` which means that `std::ios::failure` changes size depending whether it derives from `system_error` or not. That's an ABI break, so we have two different `ios::failure` types defined, and which one is visible depends on the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro. If libstdc++.so throws the old type and you try to catch the new type (or vice versa) it fails. But I used magic in GCC 8 so it works

Comment: Should catch const exception: `catch (const std::exception &e)`

Answer (score 3):

N.B. `std::ifstream::failure` is a type defined in the `std::ios_base` base class of `ifstream`,  so the rest of this answer refers to it as `std::ios_base::failure` or just `std::ios::failure`.

The problem here is that since GCC 5 there are two different definitions of `std::ios_base::failure` in libstdc++ (see the [Dual ABI docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) for more details). That's needed because C++11 changed the definition of `ios::failure` from:

```
class ios_base::failure : public exception {
```

to:

```
class ios_base::failure : public system_error {
```

This is an ABI change, because `system_error` has additional data members compared to `exception`, and so it changes the size and layout of `ios::failure`.

So since GCC 5.1, when your code names `std::ios_base::failure` (or `std::ifstream::failure` or any other name for it) which definition you get depends on the value of the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro. And when an iostream error happens inside the `libstdc++.so` library, which type gets thrown depends on the value of the macro when `libstdc++.so` was built. If you try to catch one type and the library throws the other type, the catch won't work. This is what you're seeing. In your code `std::ifstream::failure` names the new type, but the library is throwing the old type, which is a different class, so the catch handler isn't matched.

With GCC 5.x and 6.x the code inside `libstdc++.so` throws the old type, so to catch it you need to either compile you code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` or change your handler to `catch (const std::exception&)` (because both the old and new types derive from `std::exception`).

With GCC 7.x the code inside the library throws the *new* type (changed by [PR 66145](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145)), so you need to compile your code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` or catch `std::exception`.

For GCC 8.x the library now throws an exception type that can be caught by a handler for the old type *or* the new type (changed by [PR 85222](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85222)), so you don't need to change your code. It will Just Work™.